# How do I filter a collection by type?

Tags: c#, lambda, where-clause

I have three classes:

```
public class class1 {}
public class class2 : class1 {}
public class class3 : class1 {}
```

and a list of items of `class1`, but I want to get only the ones of type `class2`, something like:

```
list = list.where(x=>x.classType == class2)
```

how is the proper way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The same way you do it outside a lambda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):-

```
var newList = list.OfType<Class2>().ToList();
```

As well as being more succinct, this has the added benefit that `newList` is of type `List<Class2>` (rather than being a `List<Class1>` which happens to contain only instances of `Class2`) saving you casting further down the line.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `GetType()` method and `typeof()`:

```
list = list.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(class2)).ToList();
```

Or, you can use `is`:

```
list = list.Where(x => x is class2).ToList();
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Here's the MSDN link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396